# How to Use WP_UnitTestCase go_to() to Simulate Current Page

Tags: wordpress, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit/WP_UnitTestCase to unit test a WP theme. I need to simulate that I'm on a page with a certain slug, and I've been told to use go_to() to do this. However, I can't figure out how to actually use the function.

If I do something like this, it won't work:

```
$this->go_to('test');
$this->assertTrue(is_page('test'));
```

Any Advice?

Answer (score 0):

The `go_to` function requires a url
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes/testcase.php#L420